# Use two column to compare date and use column in adddays

Tags: php, laravel-8

Let's suppose I have these two sql table (yes, they don't make sense, but that's not important. It is just an example.).

Table 1 Games

- id - int
- daySinceReleasedDate
- int console_id

Table 2 - Console

- id - int
- releasedDate - Date

Here is what I want in MYSQL:

```
select * from `game` where exists (select * from `console` where `game`.`console_id` = `console`.`id` and DATE('2022-05-10') >= DATE_ADD(`console`.`releasedDate `, INTERVAL `daySinceReleasedDate` DAY))
```

Here is what I try, but it does not work:

```
$game= Game::whereHas('console', function($q) {
            $q->whereDate(now(), '>=', 'releasedDate'->addDays('daySinceReleasedDate'));
       })
```

Comment: You'll need to use the DATE_ADD bit you have with a `DB::raw()`.

Comment: Does you raw query work?

Comment: Does you raw query work?
Yes